# Set Watermark on Document Using CMIS After view or download

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis

I have Created Custom web Application using Java Servlets, and Connected to Alfresco Repository using CMIS.

I also have created one simple workflow using activity.

Now My requirement is, In workflow after view or download document i want to dynamically set the watermark on only downloaded copy. but not on original document which is in the repository.

How can i achieve this using CMIS.

Please provide sample code if you have.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Write some code that downloads the file through CMIS, adds a watermark then passes that on to the end user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the document downloaded, you are dealing with a straight Java File object at that point. CMIS is out-of-the-picture. You can use any library that knows how to work with PDFs to add a watermark. One example is [iText](http://developers.itextpdf.com/apis).